# VBA speeding up reading csvs from large non local folder

Tags: vba

I was looking at a macro that imports several csvs from a fileserver. Running the macros takes a few seconds (20ish) to initialize before the first csv gets imported. the imports themselves happen fairly quick. If I run the amcro a second time, ther eis no delay.
When I manually open the folder on the file server with explorer it also takes quite a while (30 secs or so) until all the files are shown, so I assume the macro also has to wait until the relevant files are loaded. So, my question: Is there a way to have excel automatically index that folder to be able to open it quicker or can I already run a process in the background when opening the excel file that would read out the folder?
Cheers,
CE

Edit: I can not archive the folder and make it slimmer

Comment: Sounds like antivirus slowed it down (they always scan all items on first encounter). You might want to make a local copy first - launch robocopy to mirror it to local. Then have the macro to open local ones.

Answer (score 1):

The file might be cached in memory, thereby avoiding lengthy disk I/O. You need to monitor your machine activity in terms of CPU, I/O and Network activity to figure out where the time is spent. Launch perfmon.msc and add the relevant counters to do so.

Comment: Thanks Tarik, I will have a look at perfmon.msc. never used that before